# App keep crashing after trying to create new activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-activity, android-manifest

I wanted to Create A Second Activity to my App and then the App gives black screen and crashes every time it switches to the new Activity.

The app works perfectly when disable the new activity. I tried a lot to fix it but no use. I maybe miss something .

Please Notice I Made the 2nd activity LAUNCHER category and changed the first to DEFAULT and the Emulator don't show the app when running it said that it's installed but it wont run and it's not on the Virtual Mobile Menu.

**Here is the 2nd Activity xml File :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/WelcomeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:text="Welcome !"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Play"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/WelcomeText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="S t a r t   G a m e" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/QuitMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
    android:text="Quit Game" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Here it the Java Code of it :**

```
    package com.example.write_example;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Play);
    Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuitMenu);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
   startActivity (newIntent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));             
        }
    });

       exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}



  }
```

**And Here is The Manifest Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.write_example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="1"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="standard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainMenu" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any Help Is Appreciated , Thanks for your time .

Comment: May you add the logcat of your crash ?

Comment: @gahfy I would love to add it but when I choose "save Log to a text file " it gives a long text in the log text file and it eats the whole page here

Comment: @SoulsReaper You can just multi select the lines that deal with your crash and then click save, that way only the relevant stacktrace can be posted on here

Comment: In Eclipse, just select the first line of log you want to share, then press shift and select last line. Then do Ctrl + C. Paste it here.

Comment: @gahfy sorry to say that but there is no log because the app never runs after make the 2nd activity run on startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/QuitMenu"
```

So change

```
Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuitGame);// id is QuitMenu
```

to

```
Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuitMenu);
```

Edit:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MenuActivity"
    android:launchMode="standard"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

</activity>
```

And Change

```
startActivity (newIntent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));
```

To

```
startActivity (new Intent(MenuActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it i didn't notice , but sadly the activity seems crashes the app when onCreating not when clicking the button , I never saw the 2nd Activity working !

Comment: @SoulsReaper Button is initialized in onCreate you get NPE and it crashed

Comment: @SoulsReaper you have this  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MainMenu" />` and for MainActivtiy you have  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` and this  `startActivity (newIntent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));` is wrong

Comment: @SoulsReaper now check the edit make the changes see if it works

Comment: @Rughunandan The MainActivity Activity is working perfectly before making the new MainMenu Activity , I want the MainMenu Activity to run On Startup and switch when clicking buttons to the MainActivity but the problem is the App never run now after setting the activity , I tried making it DEFAULT and switch using button but still crash .

Comment: @SoulsReaper make the changes in the edit of my post and pls post the stack trace if its a crash the crash info is logged in logcat

Answer (score 1):

`QuitGame` is text property of button not id. Id is `QuitMenu`.